# How to access folders outside root directory in laravel? to be fetched with Vue

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, vuejs2

I'm trying to build a project. This project is contained in 2 seperate folders. The back-end is using laravel and the front-end is using Vue. The problem is, I need to fetch photos with vue from the laravel folder. Here is the project structure:

- Project Folder

  - Laravel Folder

    - Media Folder (Contains images to be fetched with Vue)
  - Vue Folder

Currently here is the set up. When I execute the controller in laravel, it default accesses it's own public folder and creates a folder called media. is there a way to create a path for laravel that is outside it's own root folder?

What I'd like to happen is to set the upload path outside of the laravel folder and into the **Vue** folder so that Vue can fetch the data. Alternatively, If we could find a way where **Vue** can access files outside of it's own directory, that could be a solution too.

```
$upload_path = 'media';
```

Comment: So .. the images need to be accessible from both? Seems odd that both server and client need such access to resources ... usually they either are part of the client, or part of the server

Comment: It's a project. No server yet. I just need laravel to access the vue folder or vice versa

Comment: `No server yet` how can you run laravel without a server? PHP needs a server to do anything useful, doesn't it? or is the server itself written in PHP?

Comment: oh no, sorry, miscommunication there. I thought you meant deploying on a production server. I'm just storing my laravel and vue directory inside XAMP htdocs area.